# numpy array transpose creating weird digit number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I tried transpose of 2d array in python using [*zip(*array)]
Where array looks like

```
[[0.00075 0.0125]
 [0.02    0.03  ]]
```

However, after transposing it and summing column, it returns weird value

```
[0.027500000000000004, 0.042499999999999996]
```

This is the code I used

```
array = [sum(column) for column in array.T]
```

Can anyone please explain where this  0.000000000000000004 came from?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Also, why do you transpose a NUMPY array with zip instead of `array.T`? the issue is most likely because of different float types conversion

Comment: Sorry it seems like the problem only occurs if I do [ sum(column) for column in array.T ]. So it only happens when I tried summing columns of array. I tried array.T and same result observed. I will update the question

Comment: This is just a consequence of how floats are represented in your computer: 1/2 can be represented exactly, but 1/3 not so much, and that leaves weird looking errors in the final digit of many calculations.

Comment: Why not use `np.sum(array, axis=1)` instead?